# HashCat bcrypt $2*$, Blowfish (Unix) Line-length exception

Tags: hashcat

Hello I attempting to use HashCat example hash to decrypt the example on their page using bcrypt $2*$, Blowfish (Unix)

Using the hash of there example:

```
$2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6
```

I am using this command on MAC

```
./hashcat -m 3200 $2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6
```

It gives me

```
Hash 'a-bash5.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6': Line-length exception
No hashes loaded.
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the hash inside a text file instead of pasting it into the command line. The whole file would just be `$2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6`, and then you can just pass that to hashcat, i.e. `hashcat -m 3200 hash.txt`.

If it keeps complaining about `Line-length exception`, make sure there are no spaces or newlines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Use backslash "\" before the $ sign in the hash value

./hashcat -m 3200 $2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6