# Hashcat doesn't recover passwords, though they are present in the dict

Tags: linux, hash, passwords, hashcat

I'm trying to do to a test launch of hashcat with these two passwords:

```sh
$ echo "Password" | md5sum | tr -d ' -' >> target_hashes.txt
$ echo "HELLO" | md5sum | tr -d ' -' >> target_hashes.txt
$ ls
rockyou.txt  target_hashes.txt
$ cat target_hashes.txt
29f33cab54c2a8858885b95d8fbb7ff1
0084467710d2fc9d8a306e14efbe6d0f
$ hashcat -a 0 -m 0 -o cracked.txt target_hashes.txt rockyou.txt
hashcat (v6.1.1) starting...

Hashes: 2 digests; 2 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 16 bits, 65536 entries, 0x0000ffff mask, 262144 bytes, 5/13 rotates
Rules: 1

Applicable optimizers applied:
* Zero-Byte
* Early-Skip
* Not-Salted
* Not-Iterated
* Single-Salt
* Raw-Hash

Dictionary cache hit:
* Filename..: rockyou.txt
* Passwords.: 14344385
* Bytes.....: 139921498
* Keyspace..: 14344385

Approaching final keyspace - workload adjusted.

Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Exhausted
Hash.Name........: MD5
Hash.Target......: target_hashes.txt
Time.Started.....: Wed Nov 18 12:40:22 2020 (17 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Wed Nov 18 12:40:39 2020 (0 secs)
Guess.Base.......: File (rockyou.txt)
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........:   843.6 kH/s (1.31ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:1 Thr:1 Vec:8
Recovered........: 0/2 (0.00%) Digests
Progress.........: 14344385/14344385 (100.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/14344385 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 14344385/14344385 (100.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:0 Amplifier:0-1 Iteration:0-1
Candidates.#1....: $HEX[206b72697374656e616e6e65] -> $HEX[042a0337c2a156616d6f732103]

Started: Wed Nov 18 12:40:18 2020
Stopped: Wed Nov 18 12:40:41 2020
```

They are clearly present in the dict, but somewhy hashcat doesn't recover them. I've tried this under WSL and on Kali itself: both produce no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `echo -n` instead of `echo` otherwise your password will include a trailling `\n` (newline character), which Hashcat will not try to match.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the problem is still present when I copypaste hashes into the target txt file from any other sources.

Comment: Might be that a newline is automatically being added to the end of the txt file? Sounds similar to the problem in this question, which was fixed by making sure no newlines existed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200893/2521402

Comment: @AndrewZick It looks like ```echo "abc" | md5sum ``` takes into account the trailing newline and the hash output will be different from what I wanted. ```-n``` flag is also necessary when copypasting